# Retrieve and display multiple images from URL

Tags: swift, xcode, xcode8, alamofire, alamofireimage

Experimenting with Swift3, Alamofire and AlamofireImage. I am trying to display some Instagram images in a tableview. I have a `data.json` file of **Places** retrieved using Alamofire which look like this:

```
{
  "places" : [
    { "name" : "place1", "url" : "http://instagramImage1.jpg" },
    { "name" : "place2", "url" : "http://instagramImage2.jpg" },
    { "name" : "place3", "url" : "http://instagramImage3.jpg" },
  ]
}
```

I have setup `PlaceTableViewCell` with a `UIImageView` and attached it to an outlet in the corresponding controller.

I also have a `PlaceTableViewController` which includes:

```
var places = [Place]() //empty array to store places
```

In `viewDidLoad()` method I call a private function:

```
loadJson()
```

and the function looks like this:

```
private func loadJson() {
    Alamofire.request("https://example.com/data.json").responseJSON { response in
        if let JSON = response.result.value as? [String : Any],
            let places = JSON["places"] as? [[String : String]] {
            for place in places {
                //should I call loadImage() function here?
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I also have a model for each place in the JSON file:

```
import UIKit

class Place {

    var name: String
    var url: String

    init?(name: String, url: String) {
        self.name = name
        self.url = url     
    }

}
```

**QUESTION**

I'm not sure where to go from here. I would like to use AlamofireImage (which I have included in my project) to download each image but can I do this in a loop of some sort? I would also like to show each image in a new table row. Any advice and code examples would be much appreciated.

Comment: In each cells of the row, load the image with AlamofireImage. If you do it in the `loadJSON()`, you'll prefetch all the images, that's true, but if the user don't scroll to see each one of them, you'll prefetch for nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend not fetch the image in `loadJSON`.

**Why?**

- There could be a large number of photos coming back in the initial request, and the user may never even scroll down in the application far enough to see some of them.
- On top of that, if you initialize too many requests simultaneously, some of the requests may time out while waiting for other requests to finish. So this is probably not the best solution.

So, now coming to the solution. It makes sense to download the image data for only the cells that the user is attempting to view.

`TableView` has a delegate method for this purpose only

```
optional func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, 
        willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, 
           forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
```

Use this method to load the images.

```
extension ViewController: UITableViewDelegate {
   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, 
        willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, 
           forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let photoURL = places[indexPath.row].url

    // fetch this photo from web using URL

    // get the table view cell and update the image
     if let cell = self.tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as UITableViewCell {
         cell.imageView.image = //fetchPhoto
     }   
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. `places.count` is giving me 0 when trying to set numberOfRowInSection. Any idea how I make sure the JSON data is fetched before setting number of rows?

Comment: Was thinking of placing `self.tableView.reloadData()` at the end of the `loadJson()` function?

Comment: In this case you don't need to reload the data if you are updating your image on mainQueue.

Comment: To fetch the places result first, put it in viewDidLoad and fetch the data on mainQueue and then reload the tableView dataSource.

Comment: Just trying your extension now. Is this written in Swift3?

Comment: Yes. But you will need to fill the code for fetching photos from url and updating the imageView for your cell. If you provide me your ViewController code, I can help you write it.

Comment: Thanks. Firstly I'm getting: `Value of type 'UITableView' has no member 'cellForItem'`

Comment: Sorry it have `cellForRow` properties.

Comment: To use the extension do I just add it beneath my PlaceTableViewController? I've never used one before. If so then how do I refer to `places` array as it's in the main class.

Comment: Yes, you can even write it in a separate file, that is not an issue. https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Extensions.html

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141984/discussion-between-rahul-and-tommyd456).

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code in your tableview controller to populate image in cell. For that you will also require to create one cell in tableview or create custom cell with xib. My code is for loading the custom cell from xib take a look.

```
 //MARK:- TableView Delegate and DataSource
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection sectionIndex: Int) -> Int {
    return places.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 200//or cell height you want
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
     var cell  = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PlaceCell") as? PlaceCell
    if cell == nil {
        cell = (loadFromNibNamed(viewClass: PlaceCell.self) as! PlaceCell)
    }

    cell?.ivCategory.af_setImage(withURL: URL(string: places[indexPath.row].url)) 
    return cell!
}
```

Also note that you will have to reload tableview once you get response from api.

Comment: Thanks for this. I'm not actually using xib file. I should have mentioned in my question.